# How do I tell dartdoc to document everything?

Tags: dart

I've tried to lay out my classes in one file each, with the classes belonging to a couple different libraries.

Basically, these files have `library inf.logic;` at the top:

- `web/logic/realm.dart` (imports `region.dart`)
- `web/logic/region.dart` (imports `../events.dart`)
- `web/logic/tile.dart`

This has `library inf.gfx;`:

- `web/gfx/viewport.dart` (imports `../logic/realm.dart`)

This has just `library inf;`:

- `web/events.dart`

And then I have the main entry point, which seems to end up in the `inf` library by default:

- `web/inf.dart` (imports `gfx/viewport.dart`, `logic/realm.dart`, `logic/region.dart`, `logic/tile.dart`)

When I generate dartdoc, it only seems to catch some classes, seemingly randomly. Even though the main entry point uses all of the above classes explicitly, I only get docs generated for `region.dart` and `events.dart`. No other files are included, and the links in the doc that refers to the other classes result in 404's.

It feels like I'm doing something wrong. Should I resort to create a wrapper file for the libraries and use `part` and `part of`? I really dislike the idea of adding that need for maintenance between file relations, that should already be implicit from the imports.

Also, how can I get rid of relative paths? I tried `package:inf/logic/realm.dart`, but it doesn't work…

Comment: I'll ask a dartdoc guy to have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei Mouravski answered this on the mailing list:

There are several issues here:

1. If Dartdoc is generating 404 links, then file a bug with all information you can possibly provide. It's very possible something broke. dartbug.com/new
2. You can document multiple things at the same time by passing multiple entrypoints. Note: if you have multiple entrypoints, you should use the 'pkg' command line option to specify your packages folder.
3. You shouldn't need a wrapper file, but dartdoc should document every library that was imported in the entrypoint, so a possibility is to just have a simple file that imports all the libraries you want documented. We're working on something better for this, and I'm sorry it's a little broken at the moment.